# Extracting and mapping geoTIFF data 1+ standard deviations from mean in R

Tags: r, mapping, raster

I have several geoTIFF files generated by Google Earth Engine (GEE) from Landsat 8 scenes. Each files covers 100Km^2, with each pixel covering 30m^2 and containing a calculated value of Land Surface Temperature (LST).

I've asked about doing this with ArcGIS Pro separately but I'd rather use R.  The Raster package looks like it'd do the job, but I have no experience of it or using raster data in R.

I need to map values that are >1 standard deviation from the mean (smaller increments would be handy, too).

Ideally, I would be able to batch process the TIFFs, and if possible I have a vector mask exported from GEE that I would like to add, too, though I expect that'd be easiest to do as a seperate process.

I'm not sure where to start with this, and, specifically, the logical order of operations in R.  If you're familiar with the Raster package any pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have to calculate the mean and sd values for raster and then find cells which value is bigger than mean+sd.

```r
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
plot(r)
```

[image]

To calculate mean and sd we will use `cellStats()` function:

```r
sdVal <- cellStats(r, "sd")
meanVal <- cellStats(r, mean)
```

Now, just copy raster `r` to `s` and replace all values which are lower than `mean+sd`

```r
s<-r
s[which(s[] < (meanVal + sdVal))] <- NA
plot(s)
```

[image]

For batch you can create a loop, or list of your rasters and `lapply()` a function to it.

For masking with vector please check `mask()` function.

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that looks like just the framework I need to help me get the job done.  :). I'll mark it answered once I've had a chance to work through the code.  :)